# Some trouble with strtok() in c?

Tags: c

I use `strtok()` to split a string and convert it to a struct, but when I add the struct to list, the previous struct ​​is changed.

The convert function:

```
Product convertStringToProduct(char *strPtr) {
    char *str = strPtr;
    char* regex = "|";
    char* token = strtok(str,regex);
    
    char* code;
    char* name;
    char* unit;
    int quantity;
    char* dateAdd;
    bool status;
    int i  = 0;
    while(true){
        if(i==0){
            code = token;
        }else if(i == 1){
            name = token;
        }else if(i == 2){
            quantity = atoi(token);
        }else if(i == 3){
            unit = token;
        }else if(i == 4){
            dateAdd = token;
        }else if(i == 5){
            status = checkBoolean(token);
        }else{
            break;
        }
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
    }
    date fdateAdd = convertStringToDate(dateAdd);
    Product pro = {code, name, quantity, unit, fdateAdd.day, fdateAdd.month, fdateAdd.year, status};
    
    return pro;
}
```

and my insert-struct-to-list function:

```
struct date{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

typedef struct date date;

struct product {
    char* code;
    char* name;
    int quantity;
    char* unit;
    struct date dateAdd;
    bool status;
};

typedef struct product Product; 
typedef struct date Date; 

void insertProduct(Product** listProductPtr, size_t *lengthPtr, Product product) {
    printf("[insertProduct]]INFO: Product Name before insert: %s \n", product.name);
    
    printf("[insertProduct] Address of variable in caller: %p\n", (void*)listProductPtr);
    if (*lengthPtr)
        printf("[insertProduct] Address of first product: %p\n", (void*)*listProductPtr);  // Same: &((*listProduct)[0])

    Product *tmp = realloc(*listProductPtr, sizeof(Product) * ( (*lengthPtr) + 1));
    if (!tmp) {
        printf("ERROR__________________realloc failed");
    }

    *listProductPtr = tmp;
    (*listProductPtr)[(*lengthPtr)++] = product;


    printf("[insertProduct] Address of variable in caller: %p\n", (void*)listProductPtr);
    if (*lengthPtr)
        printf("[insertProduct] Address of first product: %p\n", (void*)*listProductPtr);  // Same: &((*listProduct)[0])
}

void readDataFromFile(Product **listProductPtr, size_t *lengthPtr, const char *fileName) {
    printf("[readDataFromFile] Address of variable in caller: %p\n", (void*)listProductPtr);
    if (*lengthPtr)
        printf("[readDataFromFile] Address of first product: %p\n", (void*)*listProductPtr);  // Same: &((*listProduct)[0])

    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
       printf("ERROR__________________can not open file");
    }

    char buff[1024];
    Product product;
    while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL) {
        product = convertStringToProduct(buff);
        printf("[readDataFromFile]INFO: Product Name after conver: %s, Current length %d\n", product.name,  lengthPtr);
        insertProduct(listProductPtr, lengthPtr, product);
    }

    fclose(fp); 

    printf("[readDataFromFile] Address of variable in caller: %p\n", (void*)listProductPtr);
    if (*lengthPtr)
        printf("[readDataFromFile] Address of first product: %p\n", (void*)*listProductPtr);  // Same: &((*listProduct)[0])
}

int main(void) {
    Product *listProduct = NULL;
    size_t length = 0;

    printf("[main] Address of listProduct variable: %p\n", (void*)&listProduct);
    if (length)
        printf("[main] Address of first product: %p\n", (void*)listProduct);  // Same: &(listProduct[0])

    const char *fileName = "products.txt";
    readDataFromFile(&listProduct, &length, fileName);    
    
    printf("[main] Address of listProduct variable: %p\n", (void*)&listProduct);
    if (length)
        printf("[main] Address of first product: %p\n", (void*)listProduct);

    size_t i;
    for( i=0; i<length; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", listProduct[i].name);
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:
The product, after converting, is correct, but `strtok()` or `convertStringToProduct` make all values in list the same last product

```
[insertProduct]]INFO: Product Name before insert: FOOD 1
[insertProduct] Address of variable in caller: 000000000062FE08
[insertProduct] Address of variable in caller: 000000000062FE08
[insertProduct] Address of first product: 0000000000B413E0
[readDataFromFile]INFO: Product Name after conver: FOOD 2, Current length 6487552
[insertProduct]]INFO: Product Name before insert: FOOD 2
[insertProduct] Address of variable in caller: 000000000062FE08
[insertProduct] Address of first product: 0000000000B413E0
[insertProduct] Address of variable in caller: 000000000062FE08
[insertProduct] Address of first product: 0000000000B413E0
[readDataFromFile]INFO: Product Name after conver: FOOD 3, Current length 6487552
[insertProduct]]INFO: Product Name before insert: FOOD 3
[insertProduct] Address of variable in caller: 000000000062FE08
[insertProduct] Address of first product: 0000000000B413E0
[insertProduct] Address of variable in caller: 000000000062FE08
[insertProduct] Address of first product: 0000000000B413E0
[readDataFromFile] Address of variable in caller: 000000000062FE08
[readDataFromFile] Address of first product: 0000000000B413E0
[main] Address of listProduct variable: 000000000062FE08
[main] Address of first product: 0000000000B413E0
FOOD 3
FOOD 3
FOOD 3

--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.04992 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Your struct `Product` saves most elements using pointer, such as `char* code`, which is not an independant data, only a reference to some data field that would be modified by following `strtok`.

Comment: You probably need to use `strdup()` to duplicate the string found by `strtok()` so that the next input doesn't overwrite all the data previously saved in the structures.  You'll also need to free that memory when you're done with the structures.

Answer (score 0):

As you observe, there is nothing wrong with parsing the products as such, and there isn't anything wrong with the list manipulation either. However, when you pass the structs as values in the functions, you are making a shallow copy. The structs are copied, but pointers still point at the old values.

Simplified a little from your code, you can see the difference here:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct product
{
    char *name;
};

typedef struct product Product;

void insertProduct(Product **listProductPtr, size_t *lengthPtr, Product product)
{
    Product *tmp = realloc(*listProductPtr, sizeof(Product) * ((*lengthPtr) + 1));
    assert(tmp);

    *listProductPtr = tmp;
    (*listProductPtr)[(*lengthPtr)++] = product;
}

int main(void)
{
    Product *listProduct = NULL;
    size_t length = 0;

    insertProduct(&listProduct, &length, (Product){.name = "foo"});
    insertProduct(&listProduct, &length, (Product){.name = "bar"});
    insertProduct(&listProduct, &length, (Product){.name = "baz"});
    insertProduct(&listProduct, &length, (Product){.name = "qux"});

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", listProduct[i].name);
    }
    free(listProduct);
    listProduct = 0;
    length = 0;

    char *name = malloc(4);
    Product prod = {.name = name};
    strcpy(name, "foo");
    insertProduct(&listProduct, &length, prod);
    strcpy(name, "bar");
    insertProduct(&listProduct, &length, prod);
    strcpy(name, "baz");
    insertProduct(&listProduct, &length, prod);
    strcpy(name, "qux");
    insertProduct(&listProduct, &length, prod);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", listProduct[i].name);
    }

    free(name);
    free(listProduct);

    return 0;
}
```

In the first list I construct, each struct's name points to a new string, and the elements in the list reflect this. However, in the second list, the structs name pointer all point to the same buffer, so when I modify it, I modify them all.

The token that `strtok()` returns points into the buffer it is parsing. It is not a copy of it, which should be clear since you do not need to free it. This means that if you keep pointers into that string, and you then change the string, all those pointers will see the changes. Worse if you delete the string, then dereferencing those pointers is undefined behaviour.

I believe we are in undefined behaviour territory here, since the buffer you use for reading the data from file is freed before you run though the list to print it, but since it is stack allocated and you do not overwrite it before you print, you don't see that effect but only that the strings are all the same.

It's a bit weird, though, that they all happened to point to the same place, but I suppose that if the input has fixed width fields before the name, that could happen. It is easy enough to check if this is happening, though; run through the list and see if the pointers are the same. Don't print them as strings, but as pointers, and it should be clear. If that is the case, then obviously that is also the problem.

Then, if you want to keep the names, you should allocate memory for them and copy them there. Using `strdup()` is the usual approach, and `malloc()` + `strcpy()` is the standard compliant approach.

Do something like

```c
  name = strdup(token);
```

or

```c
  name = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
  strcpy(name, token);
```